# JSDoc: make param required/optional based on another param

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have two parameters, `limit` and `page`. If `page` is passed, `limit` is required. Otherwise, `limit` is optional. Below is my current JSDoc. How can I modify it (if this is possible) to properly show the relationship between the two?

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param {Number} [ctx.request.body.limit] A limit on the number of items to return
 * @param {Number} [ctx.request.body.page] The page we are currently on. A `limit` must also be
 *                                         given when using this parameter
 */
```